# mysql charset latin1 into utf-8 conversion issue

Tags: utf-8, latin1

My client's web app has large database which millions of records. All table's encoding is latin1.

When I fetch some text field which holds huge data and mail that string some strange haracter issue comes. Such when I recieve email spaces are converted into this character Â.
It is not premissible to change the DB encoding.
I tried the following PHP function but no outcome ;(

```
$msg = mb_convert_encoding($msg, "UTF-8", "latin1");
```

Please help

Comment: http://us2.php.net/iconv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check for the encoding php thinks it is

```
echo mb_detect_encoding($str);
```

And then do

```
iconv("detectedEncoding", "UTF-8", $str);
```

Or if iconv is not installed, check if your encoding was right in your solution. ;)